# Google Sheets API (v4) - `AutoResizeDimensions` not working

Tags: asp.net-core, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I've got a system that generates and automatically maintains lots of spreadsheets on a Drive account.

Whenever I add data to the sheet I run a 'format' method to pass over and make sure everything is ok.

This generally does things like:

- set the default font and size across the sheet
- set up the heading row
- freeze rows

In addition, I have the code below to make sure the first two columns (index 0 and 1) in the sheet are autoresizing to fit their contents. when I run it though, this element doesn't seem to make a difference. The font, column freezes etc all work.

Other notes:

- I only want those 2 columns to auto-resize
- the amount of rows in a sheet can vary
- this job is appended to the end of several in `requestList`

My code:

```
requestList.Requests.Add(new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Request()
{
    AutoResizeDimensions = new AutoResizeDimensionsRequest()
    {
        Dimensions = new DimensionRange()
        {
            SheetId = Convert.ToInt32(sheetId),
            Dimension = "COLUMNS",
            StartIndex = 0,
            EndIndex = 1
        }
    }
});

var updateRequest = sheetService.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(requestList, spreadSheetId);
var updateResponse = updateRequest.Execute();
```

Could the order which I request the 'format' changes be affecting things maybe? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DimensionRange),

> the start index is inclusive and the end index is exclusive.

So, For the first two columns, it should be

```
startIndex = 0, 
endIndex = 2
```